# Ambiguous column reference when joining

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

Structs

```
type Client struct {
   Id int64
   Name string
}

type Trade struct {
   Id int64
   ClientId int64
   Client *Client
}
```

Query
`db.Model(&Trade).Where("id = ", tradeId).Relation("Client").Select()`

Error encountered: Column Id ambiguous. Not sure what's the proper way to work around this
Would be great if someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try qualifying the `Id` column with either an alias or the full table name, e.g.

```
db.Model(&Trade).Where(`"Trade".id = ?`, tradeId).Relation("Client").Select()
```